# Chrome Dev Tools : save custom geolocation in Dev Tools Presets

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, geolocation, google-chrome-devtools

I use Developers Tools on Chrome for testing my javascript application.

But do you have an idea for change and SAVE presets of geolocation in Chrome Dev Tools (ALT+MAJ+I on mac) > Console > More (...) > Sensors > Geolocation ?

Thanks for help.

[image]

Comment: It's [hardcoded](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/emulation/SensorsView.js?q=UIstring+"mountain+view"+-file:test&sq=package:chromium&dr=C&l=441). Open a feature request on https://crbug.com

Comment: I also think this should be added.

Comment: @ntpulse Have you opened a feature request? I'm interested in this as well.

Answer (score 3):

Alas, as of June 2017 this feature is not implemented yet.

**But** there's a feature request for this exact feature => https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=649657

The best way to obtain what you are asking for is to:

1. Log-in with a Google account.
2. Visit the [feature request link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=649657).
3. Click on the star near the issue number.
4. Hope Google will implement the feature ;-)

Comment: Everyone that reads this: Please go to the feature request link and star it like described above. The more attention it gets, the more is the chance it gets implemented!